# VBS Script, CopyFile File

Tags: windows, vbscript, scripting

I am new to vbs scripting, I have been working on a script to create a directory with user input. Then the script copies a specific file into the newly created directory. I can't seem to get the file into the newly created directory. any help would be great!!

```
 dim UserName
Do
   UserName = InputBox ("Enter Client Name with no spaces IE: lastname_firstname")
   If UserName = "" then
      Msgbox "No Username entered"
   end if
Loop Until UserName <> ""

MsgBox "Please click OK to continue"

MsgBox "Check \\server\path\share\ for NEW client folder"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c mkdir \\server\path\share\" & UserName

sPath = "\\server\path\share\"
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "explorer /n," & sPath & UserName, 1, False
Set oShell = Nothing

dim filesys
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists("\\server\path\share\some_type_file.docx") Then
filesys.CopyFile "\\server\path\share\some_type_file.docx", "\\server\path\share\" <<COPY FILE INTO NEWLY CREATED DIRECTORY "UserName">> 
End If
```

Comment: what problem/error are you facing ?

Comment: Is this a copy/paste problem or are you missing the `& UserName` at the end of the `CopyFile` call?

Comment: `filesys.CopyFile "\\server\path\share\some_type_file.docx", "\\server\path\share\"`  copies the file to the base directory.  `"\\server\path\share\some_type_file.docx", "\\server\path\share\" & UserName & "\"` breaks the script, the newly created path cannot be found, the directory `\\server\path\share\UserName` exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the last line to this

```
    filesys.CopyFile "\\server\path\share\some_type_file.docx", "\\server\path\share\" & UserName & "\"
```